# Enable NTFS long paths through Inno Setup Compiler script

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

My application needs to have long paths enabled. I figured out that enabling long paths in registry through .iss script is quite well documented, but what I also have to do is to Enable NTFS long paths.
Manually I would do it  like that:
`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths`. Is there a way to do it through .iss script, so that it would be done while installation?

Comment: Consider asking on Super User *"How to enable NTMS long path programmatically from command-line/powershell/whatever"*. And we can then help you re-implement that in Inno Setup (though it would probably be trivial).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it, it is

```
System\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem -> LongPathsEnabled
```